# Dart intl how to omit name and arguments

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-intl

I am trying to omit passing name and arguments into `Intl.message`. `Intl` documentation suggests that, there is a transformer provided that will automatically insert those parameters for you.

So I added following into `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dev_dependencies:
  intl_translation: ^0.17.3
transformers:
- intl_translation:
$include: lib/localization.dart
```

In my `localization.dart` I have following method:

```dart
class AppLocalizations {
  ...
  String greetingMessage(String name) => Intl.message(
    "Hello $name!",
    desc: "Greet the user as they first open the application",
    examples: const {'name': "Emily"});
}
```

When I run `flutter pub pub run intl_translation:extract_to_arb --output-dir=strings lib/localization.dart` I have the following error:

```
<Intl.message("Hello $name!", desc: "Greet the user as they first open the application", examples: const {'name' : "Emily"})>
    reason: The 'args' argument for Intl.message must be specified for messages with parameters. Consider using rewrite_intl_messages.dart
```

How I can enable that transformer?

Answer (score 0):

Your error:

> *reason: The 'args' argument for Intl.message must be specified for
>   messages with parameters. Consider using rewrite_intl_messages.dart*

Is because your `Intl.message()` has an argument in it, `name`, so you must also add: `args: [name]`

```
String greetingMessage(String name) => Intl.message(
  "Hello $name!",
  args: [name]
  desc: "Greet the user as they first open the application",
  examples: const {'name': "Emily"});
```

See: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/Intl/message.html

> The args is a list containing the arguments of the enclosing function.
>   **If there are no arguments, args can be omitted.**

But you do have an argument, so it cannot be omitted.